# Does Open vSwitch put attached interfaces into promiscuous mode?

Tags: linux, openvswitch, promiscuous

When I use Linux bridging to bridge a virtual machine to a physical NIC, I have to explicitly set the NIC to promiscuous mode so that ethernet frames that were destined for the VM would make it to the bridge.

Is this required when using Open vSwitch, or does Open vSwitch put network interfaces attached to the bridge into promiscuous mode automatically?

Answer (score 1):

According to this document (http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/networking/w/wiki/3820.openvswitch-openflow-lets-get-started.aspx), you also need to set the interface in promiscuous mode.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.